# PropertiesService - scope question. How to separate properties between organizations

Tags: google-apps-script

I have a question regarding the scope of PropertiesService. I'm developing a calendar add-on that relies on a data in spreadsheet. I use a ScriptProperty to hold the ID of the spreadsheet.

Now I'd like to publish my add-on on the marketplace but the thing is that each deployment(organization) should have their own spreadsheet.

As far as I understand ScriptProperties would span over all deployments, so it's not the best idea to hold it there(is it?) but I have no idea where else I could store it?

Is there an option for such case?

Answer (score 1):

### [Class PropertiesService](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/properties/properties-service) offers three methods:

- [getDocumentProperties()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/properties/properties-service#getdocumentproperties)
- [getScriptProperties()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/properties/properties-service#getscriptproperties)
- [getUserProperties()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/properties/properties-service#getuserproperties)

Thereby `getUserProperties()` gets a property store that only the current user can access, and only within this script.

So this is the property service you should use if you desire every user having his own values for a property.

Comment: Thank you for your answer but actualy I forgot to add one more requirement to my problem - property has to be shared between users within a single deployment/organization. Meaning, if property is set/updated by a single user - other users within this organization should see updated value.

Comment: You'd probably need to set-up your Add-on in such a way that when it is run for the first time, it prompts the user to introduce a spreadsheetId that you can store in the user properties. It would be up to the users of the same organization to provide the Id their organization agreed on.

Comment: yeah. I have that as a 'backup solution'. I'd rather have a solution that allows to set it once for whole organization.

Comment: I am sorry not to be able to offer you a more suitable solution. Maybe you can file a [feature request](https://developers.google.com/issue-tracker) on Public's Issue Tracker asking to implement domain-wide properties?